# problems scraping web just after login - Error 403 (python & selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a code for web scraping using python and selenium, usually I have no problems, but this time just after login I have an error 403 and I can't to continue. I don't know how fix it. Can you help me? Thank you!

```
import os
from os import remove
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
chromedriver = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) ) + "/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.twitter.com") #this is only an example
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/input[3]")
email.send_keys("test@email.com")
pwd = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/input[4]").send_keys("Ykvn@nh21")    
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/input[5]").click() 
time.sleep(7)
#just here I have the error 403 and I can't to continue
```

Comment: You have forbidden access. Possibly scraped that website too much and they blocked your ip

Comment: Hello! I tried from several IP and other laptops, but the problem is the same. I been reading about this on this site:
https://www.zenrows.com/blog/web-scraping-login-python#scraping-behind-the-login-on-waf-protected-websites
"https://www.zenrows.com/blog/web-scraping-login-python#scraping-behind-the-login-on-waf-protected-websites"
But I could not to fix it.